# Parallel use of main, scanf and timer threads in C

Tags: c, multithreading, timer, pthreads, scanf

I want to realise a little game around the use of multithreading. Here is the concept :

- A question is asked to a user through Linux console.
- As soon as this question is asked, a timer of 15 seconds starts.
- If the user wants to answer the question, he writes something in the console, and the timer of the question freezes.
- Here a new timer of 5 seconds starts, which is the limited amount of time the user has to answer the question.

  - If the answer is wrong, then the question timer unfreezes and the user can try to answer again until the question timer reaches 0 second following the same pattern as seen previously.
  - If the answer is correct, then the question timer is canceled.

Of course, i've made my program to handle this game for 4 players, but i've got problems for the multithreading interactions.

My first idea consisted on 4 threads, and different signal conditions to be sent depending on what the user does or what is the timers states. (I have a test code which is rather big and contains problems, and I don't want to display it here now)

As I'm a beginner in C, can you help me with this multithread part ?
Thanks in advance :)

EDIT : Here's the first draft without stoping the question timer :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_attr_t attr_t;

void* thread_timer_q(void* arg) // Question timer thread
{
  pthread_t* a=(pthread_t*)arg;
  int t_tot=15;
  int t_ref=time(NULL);

  while(time(NULL)-t_ref<t_tot)
  {
    printf("q%d\n",time(NULL)-t_ref); // Just to see the timer going on
    sleep(1);
  }

  pthread_cancel(*a); // Here is to kill the associated scanf thread
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void* thread_timer_r(void* arg) // Answer timer thread
{
  pthread_t* a=(pthread_t*)arg;
  int t_tot=5;
  int t_ref=time(NULL);

  while(time(NULL)-t_ref<t_tot)
  {
    printf("...r%d\n",time(NULL)-t_ref); // To see the timer going on
    sleep(1);
  }

  pthread_cancel(*a); // Here is to kill the associated scanf thread
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}
void* thread_scanf_q(void* arg)
{
  int *x=malloc(sizeof(int));

  scanf("%x",x);

  pthread_exit((void*)x);
}

void* thread_scanf_r(void* arg) // These two scanf threads are the same for the moment
{
  int *x=malloc(sizeof(int));

  scanf("%x",x);

  pthread_exit((void*)x);
}


int main()
{
  pthread_t* timer_q=malloc(sizeof(pthread_t));
  pthread_t* timer_r=malloc(sizeof(pthread_t));
  pthread_t* scanf_q=malloc(sizeof(pthread_t));
  pthread_t* scanf_r=malloc(sizeof(pthread_t));

  void* *retval_q=malloc(sizeof(void*));
  void* *retval_r=malloc(sizeof(void*));
  int *conv=malloc(sizeof(int));
  *conv=0;

  pthread_attr_init(&attr_t);
  pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr_t,PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED); // for timers

  printf("Question asked !\n");

  pthread_create(timer_q,&attr_t,thread_timer_q,(void*)scanf_q);  

  while(*conv!=1) // While the answer is incorrect
  {
    pthread_create(scanf_q,NULL,thread_scanf_q,NULL); // Ask if the user wants to answer

    pthread_join(*scanf_q,retval_q);

    if(*retval_q==PTHREAD_CANCELED) // If scanf_q is canceled, the question timer is off
      break;
    else
    {
      pthread_create(scanf_r,NULL,thread_scanf_r,NULL); // Asking the answer to the user
      pthread_create(timer_r,&attr_t,thread_timer_r,(void*)scanf_r);  

      pthread_join(*scanf_r,retval_r);

      if(retval_r!=PTHREAD_CANCELED) // If the user has written something
      {
        conv=(int*)(*retval_r);

        if(*conv==1) // If the answer is correct
        {
          printf("Correct answer !\n");
          pthread_cancel(*timer_q);
          pthread_cancel(*timer_r);
          return 0;
        }
      } //end if(*retval_r!=PTHREAD_CANCELED)
    }// end if(*retval_q==PTHREAD_CANCELED)
  }// end while(*conv!=1)

  return 0;
}
```

My problem here is that if the user answers an incorrect answer, the question timer stops a few seconds after, while it should have continued up to 15 seconds.

EDIT 2 : Problem solved => i didn't closed the answer timer thread if the answer was wrong, so i would just add in the inner while this :

```
if(*conv!=1)
{
  pthread_cancel(*timer_r);
}
```

Here is the new full code with a freeze of the question timer when the user wants to answer the question :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t mut=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t freeze=PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t unfreeze=PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

pthread_attr_t attr_t;

void* thread_timer_q(void* arg)
{
  pthread_t* a=(pthread_t*)arg;
  struct timespec ts={time(NULL)+1,0};
  int t_tot=15;
  int t_ref=time(NULL);

  while(time(NULL)-t_ref<t_tot)
  {
    if(ETIMEDOUT==pthread_cond_timedwait(&freeze,&mut,&ts))
    {
      ts.tv_sec++;
      printf("q%d\n",time(NULL)-t_ref);
    }
    else
    {
      printf("freezed\n");//
      t_tot-=time(NULL)-t_ref;

      while(1)
      {
        if(ETIMEDOUT==pthread_cond_timedwait(&unfreeze,&mut,&ts))
        {
          ts.tv_sec++;
        }
        else
        {
          printf("Unfreezed\n");
          t_ref=time(NULL);
          break;
        }
      }//end while(1)
    }//end if(ETIMEDOUT ...)
  }//end while

  pthread_cancel(*a);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void* thread_timer_r(void* arg)
{
  pthread_t* a=(pthread_t*)arg;
  int t_tot=5;
  int t_ref=time(NULL);

  while(time(NULL)-t_ref<t_tot)
  {
    printf("...r%d\n",time(NULL)-t_ref);
    sleep(1);
  }

  pthread_cancel(*a);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void* thread_scanf(void* arg)
{
  int *x=malloc(sizeof(int));

  scanf("%x",x);

  pthread_exit((void*)x);
}


int main()
{
  pthread_t* timer_q=malloc(sizeof(pthread_t));
  pthread_t* timer_r=malloc(sizeof(pthread_t));
  pthread_t* scanf_q=malloc(sizeof(pthread_t));
  pthread_t* scanf_r=malloc(sizeof(pthread_t));

  void* *retval_q=malloc(sizeof(void*));
  void* *retval_r=malloc(sizeof(void*));
  int *conv=malloc(sizeof(int));

  pthread_attr_init(&attr_t);
  pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr_t,PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED); // for timers

  while(1)
  {
    *conv=0;

    printf("Question asked !\n");

    pthread_create(timer_q,&attr_t,thread_timer_q,(void*)scanf_q);  

    while(*conv!=1)
    {
      pthread_create(scanf_q,NULL,thread_scanf,NULL);

      pthread_join(*scanf_q,retval_q);

      if(*retval_q==PTHREAD_CANCELED)
        break;
      else
      {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
        pthread_cond_signal(&freeze);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);

        pthread_create(scanf_r,NULL,thread_scanf,NULL);
        pthread_create(timer_r,&attr_t,thread_timer_r,(void*)scanf_r);  

        pthread_join(*scanf_r,retval_r);

        if(*retval_r==PTHREAD_CANCELED)
        {
          pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
          pthread_cond_signal(&unfreeze);
          pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
        }
        else
        {
          conv=(int*)(*retval_r);

          if(*conv==1)
          {
            printf("Correct answer !\n");
            pthread_cancel(*timer_q);
            pthread_cancel(*timer_r);
            break;
          }
          else
          {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
            pthread_cond_signal(&unfreeze);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);

            pthread_cancel(*timer_r);
          }// end if(*conv==1)
        }// end if(*retval_r=...)
      }// end if(*retval_q=...)
    }// end while(*conv!=1)
  }// end while(1)
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This seems like a pretty broad question. I recommend stripping the program down to be reasonably simple, to isolate the part which you are confused with, and then posting the code. In doing so, you might uncover the issue yourself, and if not you will make it much easier to debug.

Comment: Answer found, closed subject.